# OPENCART select products having filter_id

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

**PROBLEM**:
i want to select products with a list of filter ids.
but filters are from filter groups, so i want to have products in a way that have some filters of all filter groups
like this

**example**

filter group:
samsung,apple

filter:
8GB, 16GB

if i select these filters
i want all products which are samsung or apple and 8GB or 16GB

```
SELECT *
FROM oc_product_filter
WHERE (filter_id IN (27)) OR (filter_id IN (28,30))
```

Comment: @Strawberry i forgot to add what i did. plz check that.

Comment: Ok. Now I regret asking ;-)

Comment: Post up a fiddle.

Comment: @Strawberry i made my question simpler plz check

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @AliSamie . . . What do the integers `27`, `28`, and `30` have to do with the question you asked?

Comment: how about replacing OR with and AND. 
 
filter_Id in Brands (Apple OR Sunsung) AND filter_ID in Storage (8 OR 16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 28 & 30 are the `filter_group_id` values, you can try:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM oc_product_filter
WHERE filter_id IN (SELECT filter_id FROM oc_filter WHERE filter_group_id in(28,30))
```

This will give you a list of the `product_id`'s that have a filter that is within the filter groups 28 & 30.